# Post request to create an event using graph api createEvent is throwing "OrganizationFromTenantGuidNotFound" error

Tags: azure, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-calendar

I want to generate an online event using Microsoft graph API.

I have office 365 subscription

I have registered an application in Azure AD with account type "
Accounts in any organizational directory (Any Azure AD directory - Multitenant) and personal Microsoft accounts (e.g. Skype, Xbox)"

Not provided any redirect URL while configuration

I have given both delegated and application permissions for the application of Calendars.ReadWrite and have provided Admin consent.

Maven Dependencies

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.microsoft.azure</groupId>
        <artifactId>msal4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-nop</artifactId>
        <version>1.8.0-beta4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.microsoft.graph</groupId>
        <artifactId>microsoft-graph</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.microsoft.graph</groupId>
        <artifactId>microsoft-graph-core</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.microsoft.graph</groupId>
        <artifactId>microsoft-graph-auth</artifactId>
        <version>0.2.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>
```

I am using ClientCredentialProvider to create an auth provider. But whenever I am trying to create an event am getting "OrganizationFromTenantGuidNotFound"

```
ClientCredentialProvider authProvider =  new ClientCredentialProvider(
            CLIENT_ID,
            Arrays.asList("https://graph.microsoft.com/.default"),
            CLIENT_SECRET,
            "938db5c8-e2ce-3c76-bad7-1e00cf87b779",
            NationalCloud.Global

    );
```

Please find the stack trace here

[stacktrace](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-java-auth/files/4767108/stack_trace.txt)

Please help!

Comment: Is it correct tenant id  (938db5c8-e2ce-3c76-bad7-1e00cf87b779) ?

Comment: No, it's a dummy ID, but am using the correct one in the code

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE:** I investigated with Varun offline. In his case, the problem was he was trying to create an event in a guest user's calendar. This was a hotmail.com user that was added to his M365 tenant as a guest. This won't work because the user's mailbox (and hence, her calendar) exists outside of the M365 tenant.

From your stack trace, you're sending your POST to `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/events`. This requires a user context, since you're using the `/me` segment. However, from your code above, you are getting an app-only token, meaning you are authenticated as the app, not as any user. Trying to access any URL with `/me` will fail here.

Instead, you need to get the user's ID, then POST to `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{user-id}/events`.

Comment: No it's still giving me the same error. OrganisationFromTenantGuidNotFound

Comment: Do you have an Office 365 subscription in this tenant, with Exchange Online? Can you login with one of your users to https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer and execute any of the calendar queries?

Comment: Yes, I have the office 365 subscription and able to execute queries in graph explorer. BTW graph explorer uses delegated permissions so it wouldn't be a problem, but the problem is when using application permissions with ClientCredentialProvider

Comment: Yes I know GE uses delegated, I just wanted to make sure your tenant actually works. I've initialized the auth provider exactly as you do and it works fine. You're doing something wrong, using the wrong tenant GUID, trying to do this with a personal account (outlook.com, etc.) or something else. Have you checked your token at https://jwt.ms?

Comment: Yes I just checked with jwt.ms, decoded token has all the permissions and tenant GUID is matching with the GUID shown in the azure ad portal. I have not given any certificates, i have given only client secret, could that cause a problem? I have added supported account type as "Accounts in any organizational directory (Any Azure AD directory - Multitenant)" and have selected platform as web and given redirect URL as http://localhost:8080

Comment: I am facing exactly the same issue.
I am getting this issue on Graph Explorer [link](https://imgur.com/ezgKzZM.png)